# How to optimally copy a read-protected Clonezilla disk image?

Tags: rsync, clonezilla

Only the root user appears to have access to read the image data (plain text files in the archive have lower level of permissions). I want to transfer the backup archive in an identical form to avoid  potential issues when restoring (if any).

Is running rsync as sudo with the `--archive` and `--recursive` [options](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1) alone adequate?

---

On a further note, can *not copying over* the permissions cause complications with Clonezilla?

Comment: I would use `sudo rsync -Havn sourcedir/ targetdir` and when this *dry run* looks good, I would remove the option `n` to do the real thing. This way, and if the target file system can manage linux permissions and ownership, everything should be copied correctly.

Comment: @sudodus Does Cloezilla use hard links?

Comment: Maybe not in this particular case, but I use the option `H` as part of the standard set of options `-Havn` (it does not hurt except when there is a huge number of files, when it can make the process significantly slower). You can easily check, if there are any hard links with `ls -l` in the directory containing the Clonezilla image.

Comment: @sudodus Does `ls -l` surely list *hard* links? I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/972244) (where you participated). No results for `find -type f -links +1` in the Clonezilla directory.

Comment: You are right, to find all files in a partition, that link describes the way to do it. But with a small amount of files, you can *inspect the second column* of the output from `ls -l`, which shows the number of links to a certain inode. You are not interested in directories in this case, so `ls -l|grep -v '^d'|sort -k2` helps sort the files with hard links at the end. If you don't want to do it with your eyes (more or less directly), it is better to use the command with `find`.

Comment: Anyway, you can remove the option `H` in this case. `a` inplies `r` and several other options. `v` is for verbose, and of course optional. You may prefer the option `--info=progress2` in order to monitor the progress of the copy process, or no extra verbosity.

Comment: I have copied and restored Clonezilla images, but I have not fiddled with the permissions, so I don't know if it can cause complications. Let us assume that Clonezilla is smart enough to be satisfied as long as the files are readable, but we can be sure that there is nothing wrong with preserving the permissions and ownership (when the file system can manage it).